# Dojo Dropdowns Not able to select dropdown values because of same class value

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to click on the "Down Arrow: Element for the two different dropdowns.Both the dropdowns having same class name so am not able to differentiate between these two elements while writting the xpath.Please Help.

Please Refer Attachment for Html Code Details.

Comment: First Dropdown = <input class="dijitReset dijitInputField dijitArrowButtonInner" value="▼ " type="text" tabindex="-1" readonly="readonly" role="presentation">

Comment: Second Dropdown =<input class="dijitReset dijitInputField dijitArrowButtonInner" value="▼ " type="text" tabindex="-1" readonly="readonly" role="presentation">

Comment: The only difference for both of them is they are under different <Table>

Comment: Hi Mandar, Can you please share Code and html code? I can't see attachment

Comment: Hi Kishan , I have added the html code above.Not able to add the attachment.

Comment: I cannot see your code buddy.

Comment: The one you wrote in comment. Try with abhijeet's xpath. You can differentiate them by [1] and [2].
[1] will refer to the first element
[2] will refer to the second element

Comment: IF you still stuck then do reply me..

Comment: Hi Kishan , Not able to click on element by using xpath provided by abhijit.

Comment: Do one thing. You just click on the field where you want drop down and send me that whole html code. Please provide me something in which i can look bro. :-)

Comment: First Dropdown :-<table class="dijit dijitReset dijitInline dijitLeft dijitDownArrowButton SFE2Select mcabHtmlSelect selectValidation dijitSelect dijitValidationTextBox dijitSelectIncomplete dijitValidationTextBoxIncomplete dijitIncomplete" data-dojo-attach-point="_buttonNode,tableNode,focusNode,_popupStateNode" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" role="listbox" aria-haspopup="true" aria-labelledby="appointmentTypeLabel" id="appointmentTypeSelect" tabindex="0" aria-required="true" widgetid="appointmentTypeSelect" aria-expanded="false" aria-invalid="true" style="-webkit-user-select: none;">

Comment: <tbody role="presentation"><tr role="presentation"><td class="dijitReset dijitStretch dijitButtonContents" role="presentation"><div class="dijitReset dijitInputField dijitButtonText" data-dojo-attach-point="containerNode,textDirNode" role="presentation"><span role="option" class="dijitReset dijitInline dijitSelectLabel dijitValidationTextBoxLabel ">Please choose a topic</span></div><div class="dijitReset dijitValidationContainer"><input class="dijitReset dijitInputField dijitValidationIcon dijitValidationInner" value="Χ " type="text" tabindex="-1" readonly="readonly" role="presentation">

Comment: </div><input type="hidden" name="appointmentTypeSelect" data-dojo-attach-point="valueNode" value="" aria-hidden="true"></td><td class="dijitReset dijitRight dijitButtonNode dijitArrowButton dijitDownArrowButton dijitArrowButtonContainer" data-dojo-attach-point="titleNode" role="presentation"><input class="dijitReset dijitInputField dijitArrowButtonInner" value="▼ " type="text" tabindex="-1" readonly="readonly" role="presentation"></td></tr></tbody></table>

Comment: Second Dropdown :-

Comment: <table class="dijit dijitReset dijitInline dijitLeft dijitSelect dijitValidationTextBox dijitDownArrowButton SFE2Select mcabHtmlSelect selectValidation dijitSelectDisabled dijitValidationTextBoxDisabled dijitDisabled" data-dojo-attach-point="_buttonNode,tableNode,focusNode,_popupStateNode" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" role="listbox" aria-haspopup="true" tabindex="-1" id="uniqName_7_0" aria-disabled="true" aria-required="true" widgetid="uniqName_7_0" aria-expanded="false" aria-invalid="false" style="-webkit-user-select: none;"><tbody role="presentation">

Comment: <tr role="presentation"><td class="dijitReset dijitStretch dijitButtonContents" role="presentation"><div class="dijitReset dijitInputField dijitButtonText" data-dojo-attach-point="containerNode,textDirNode" role="presentation"><span role="option" class="dijitReset dijitInline dijitSelectLabel dijitValidationTextBoxLabel ">Please choose a sub-topic</span></div><div class="dijitReset dijitValidationContainer">

Comment: <input class="dijitReset dijitInputField dijitValidationIcon dijitValidationInner" value="Χ " type="text" tabindex="-1" readonly="readonly" role="presentation"></div><input type="hidden" name="appointmentSubTypeSelect" data-dojo-attach-point="valueNode" value="" aria-hidden="true" disabled=""></td><td class="dijitReset dijitRight dijitButtonNode dijitArrowButton dijitDownArrowButton dijitArrowButtonContainer" data-dojo-attach-point="titleNode" role="presentation">

Comment: <input class="dijitReset dijitInputField dijitArrowButtonInner" value="▼ " type="text" tabindex="-1" readonly="readonly" role="presentation"></td></tr></tbody></table>

Comment: Please find the html for 2 dropdowns above.

Comment: Very Difficult for me to understand. Just tell me test case means which website and what to do.. please

Answer (score 0):

You can write xpath like this

```
By firstElement=By.xpath("//input[@class='dijitReset dijitInputField dijitArrowButtonInner'][1]");
By secondElement=By.xpath("//input[@class='dijitReset dijitInputField dijitArrowButtonInner'][2]");
```

OR

```
List<WebElement> eleList= driver.findElements(By.xpath("//input[@class='dijitReset dijitInputField dijitArrowButtonInner']"));
eleList.get(0) #1st webelment
eleList.get(1) #2nd weblement
```

Comment: added second method. did you validate xpath in firepath? You can also write xpath in console of firefox or chrome. `$x("Write X Path here")`